# Dell PowerEdge R630 Server swap

Tags: dell, sysadmin

Our pro support with Dell is coming up on expiration for our production Dell PowerEdge R630 servers. Rather than spend approx $20k to renew pro support, our project leads have suggested another solution. They have another set of identical R630 servers they have offered to give us that have an extra 3 years of support left on them.

We recently went through an upgrade of BIOS, iDRAC, and ESXi on all of these servers. I'm trying to come up with a list of things that we need to be done if we make the switch.

I'll certainly need to do BIOS, iDRAC, and ESXi installs again on all the new servers. What else will I need to do? This may be a stupid question, but the do the VMs (vmdk files, etc.) live on these hosts?

Comment: `do the VMs (vmdk files, etc.) live on these hosts?` - How would we know?

Comment: It appears the VM files live on a datastore that is located on our SAN, so not on the servers themselves.